# Threads indefinitely waiting for timer signal

Tags: c, multithreading, timer, pthreads

I'm having trouble with creating and implementing a timer for a multithreaded program. I create 3 threads and they are supposed to wait for 1, 2, and 4 seconds, respectively. However all three threads never stop waiting and the program just sits there indefinitely.

I need 2 of my functions looked at:

**CreateAndArmTimer():**

-I'm not sure if I'm using sigemptyset and sigaddset correctly. I'm supposed to "Create the signal mask corresponding to the chosen signal_number in timer_signal". I basically looked at the man pages for [pthread_sigmask](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html) and copied what I found there.

**WaitFortimer():**

-This function is what is causing my program to not finish. My threads function normally up until this point, and once they call this function they get trapped in it and never exit.

Both functions are located at the bottom of my code. I appreciate any help with this! I can't for the life of me get this to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>



int threadNumber = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

#define NUM_THREADS    3

//used to store the information of each thread
typedef struct{
   pthread_t  threadID;
   int num;
   int policy;
   struct sched_param param;
   long startTime;
   long endTime;


   int signal_number;
   int missed_signal_count;
   int timer_Period;

   sigset_t timer_signal;

   timer_t timer_Id;



}ThreadInfo;

ThreadInfo myThreadInfo[NUM_THREADS];

void *ThreadRunner(void *vargp);
void CreateAndArmTimer(int unsigned period, ThreadInfo* threadInfo);
void WaitForTimer(ThreadInfo* threadInfo);
int sigwait(const sigset_t* set, int* sig);
int timer_create(clockid_t clockid, struct sigevent* sevp, timer_t* timerid);




//main function
int main(void){

   sigset_t alarm_sig;
   sigemptyset(&alarm_sig);
   for(int i = SIGRTMIN; i <= SIGRTMAX; i++)
   sigaddset(&alarm_sig, i);
   pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &alarm_sig, NULL);  //*****apply the blocking*****


   printf("\nrunning...\n");

   int fifoPri = 60;

   //create the 3 fifo threads
   for(int i=0; i<NUM_THREADS; i++){

         myThreadInfo[i].policy = SCHED_FIFO; 
         myThreadInfo[i].param.sched_priority = fifoPri++; 

      pthread_create(&myThreadInfo[i].threadID, NULL, ThreadRunner, &myThreadInfo[i]);

   }


   printf("\n\n");
   sleep(1);

   //tell all the threads to unlock
   pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);





   //join each thread
   for(int g = 0; g < NUM_THREADS; g++){

      pthread_join(myThreadInfo[g].threadID, NULL);

   }


   return 0;
}





//the function that runs the threads
void *ThreadRunner(void *vargp){          

   struct tm *ts;                        
   struct timeval  tv;                    
   size_t last;                           
   time_t timestamp = time(NULL);
   threadNumber++;            
   ThreadInfo* currentThread;         
   currentThread = (ThreadInfo*)vargp;
   currentThread->num = threadNumber;
   if(currentThread->num == 1){
      currentThread->timer_Period = 1000000;
   }
   else if(currentThread->num == 2){
      currentThread->timer_Period = 2000000;
   }
   else{
      currentThread->timer_Period = 4000000;
   }




        //lock the thread until it's ready to be unlocked 
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);       

        //unlocking for all other threads
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); 



   if(pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), currentThread->policy,(const struct sched_param *) &(currentThread->param))){
      perror("pthread_setschedparam failed");
      pthread_exit(NULL);
   }

   if(pthread_getschedparam(pthread_self(), &currentThread->policy,(struct sched_param *) &currentThread->param)){
      perror("pthread_getschedparam failed");
      pthread_exit(NULL);
   }


   //create and arm the timer
   printf("thread#[%d] waiting for %d seconds\n", currentThread->num, (currentThread->timer_Period/1000000));
   CreateAndArmTimer(currentThread->timer_Period, currentThread);



   //set the start time of the timer
   gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
   long startTime = (tv.tv_sec) * 1000 + (tv.tv_usec) / 1000;
   currentThread->startTime = startTime;


   //Wait for the timer
   WaitForTimer(currentThread);


   //set the end time of the timer
   gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
   long endTime = (tv.tv_sec) * 1000 + (tv.tv_usec) / 1000;
   currentThread->endTime = endTime;

   //do the printing
   printf("\nThread[%d]  Timer Delta[%lu]us           Jitter[]us\n", currentThread->num, endTime-startTime);



   pthread_exit(NULL);
}




//used to create and arm a new timer
void CreateAndArmTimer(int unsigned period, ThreadInfo* threadInfo){

   //Create a static int variable to keep track of the next available signal number
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);  
   static int nextSignalNumber = 0;  

   if(nextSignalNumber == 0){
      nextSignalNumber = SIGRTMIN;
   }
   else{
      nextSignalNumber += 1;
   }

   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); 


   threadInfo->signal_number = nextSignalNumber;


   //Create the signal mask corresponding to the chosen signal_number in "timer_signal"
   //Use "sigemptyset" and "sigaddset" for this
   sigemptyset(&threadInfo->timer_signal);
   sigaddset(&threadInfo->timer_signal, SIGQUIT);
   sigaddset(&threadInfo->timer_signal, SIGUSR1);


   //Use timer_Create to create a timer
   struct sigevent mySignalEvent;
   mySignalEvent.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
   mySignalEvent.sigev_signo = threadInfo->signal_number;
   mySignalEvent.sigev_value.sival_ptr = (void*)&(threadInfo->timer_Id);
   int ret = timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &mySignalEvent, &threadInfo->timer_Id);
   if(ret != 0){
      printf("error during timer_create for thread#[%d]\n", threadInfo->num);
   }


   //Arm timer
   struct itimerspec timerSpec;
   int seconds = period/1000000;
   long nanoseconds = (period - (seconds * 1000000)) * 1000;
   timerSpec.it_interval.tv_sec = seconds;
   timerSpec.it_interval.tv_nsec = nanoseconds;
   timerSpec.it_value.tv_sec = seconds;
   timerSpec.it_value.tv_nsec = nanoseconds;
   int ret2 = timer_settime(threadInfo->timer_Id, 0, &timerSpec, NULL);
   if(ret2 != 0){
      printf("error with timer_settime!\n");
   }

}



//used to make a thread wait for a timer
void WaitForTimer(ThreadInfo* threadInfo){


   pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &threadInfo->timer_signal, NULL); //*****unblock the signal*****


   //Use sigwait function to wait on the "timer_signal"
   int wait = sigwait(&threadInfo->timer_signal, &threadInfo->signal_number);
   if(wait != 0){
      printf("error with sigwait!\n");
   }

   //update missed_signal_count by calling "timer_getoverrun"
   threadInfo->missed_signal_count = timer_getoverrun(threadInfo->timer_Id);

}
```

When I run this, the output is:

running...

thread#[l] waiting for 1 seconds

thread#[2] waiting for 2 seconds

thread#[3] waiting for 4 seconds

Comment: Undefined behavior for unsynchronized, non-atomic, non-readonly access to an object from multiple threads.

Comment: @EOF What object are you referring to? Not that I don't believe you, I just don't see it.

Comment: @bnaecker `threadNumber`

Comment: @EOF I've never had that error. I'm running this on linux with sudo privileges/rights

Comment: @RyanWells Privileges won't protect you from undefined behavior. You're accessing (writing to) the variable `threadNumber` from many threads, without somehow synchronizing them (with a mutex or similar). You have a data race, meaning pretty much anything can happen, including the code appearing to run "normally".

Comment: Your life will be much less painful if you avoid combining Unix-signals with multithreading.  There are easier ways to implement a per-thread timer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should probably be using `pthread_sigmask(2)` rather than `sigprocmask(2)`. Besides the fact that your comments (instructions, if this is homework?) state that is to be used, the former is explicitly specified as part of the POSIX standard in multithreaded programs, while the latter is not. I don't think this matters on Linux, but it's probably good practice.

The second, and more important, is that you're not really using the signals correctly. First, you block every signal with the call to `sigprocmask(2)` in your main function, but then never change that. Inside the `CreateAndArmTimer()` function, you never actually specify that all signals *except* your `threadInfo->signal_number` should be blocked. You instead add `SIGQUIT` and `SIGUSR1` to a sigset, but then never do anything with that set. Did you mean to call `pthread_sigmask(2)` here? If so, you should be sure to add `threadInfo->signal_number` to the set too before doing so.

On the "listening" side, you never actually *unblock* any signals in the `WaitForTimer()` function (or anywhere else). Even if you correctly blocked them earlier, if you don't unblock them before calling `sigwait(2)`, they'll never be delivered to your threads. So the timer is generating the requested signals, but they're just sitting in the signal queue for your process. You must call `pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, ...)` somewhere so they can actually be delivered.

In short:

- Call `pthread_sigmask(2)` instead of `sigprocmask(2)`.
- Block all signals except your chosen `threadInfo->signal_number` in the threads.
- Unblock those signals before calling `sigwait(2)`.

Comment: I'm not understanding quite how to block signals. In my `CreateAndArmTimer` function I thought I had already created a mask to block every signal using `sigemptyset` and `sigaddset`.  And inside the 'WaitForTimer' function, I want to unblock signals using `pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK...)` but I don't understand what to do for it's arguments to unblock what I need to.

Comment: @RyanWells You did create a mask to block every signal except `SIGUSR1` and `SIGQUIT`, but you did not do anything with it. `sigaddset(2)` just adds a given value to a signal set. You need to use `sigprocmask(2)` or `pthread_sigmask(2)` to actually apply them. If you have a single signal in a set, and you call `sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &set, NULL);`, that signal will no longer be blocked. It can be hard to follow when you specify multiple signals, which is why `SIG_SETMASK` is a useful argument to `sigprocmask(2)`.

Comment: I edited my code to make changes to try to fit what you were saying (comments with asterisks). Still the same issue happening. I don't see anything wrong with the logic, I'm blocking everything then before a timer goes off I unblock the specific signal for the thread.

Comment: @RyanWells In your edited code, I still don't see where you're actually unblocking `threadInfo->signal_number`. Without doing that, the signal emitted when the timer expires is still blocked from being delivered to your threads. You need to `sigaddset(&threadInfo->timer_signal, threadInfo->signal_number);` before calling `pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &threadInfo->timer_signal, NULL);` By the way, it's really confusing to name it `threadInfo.timer_signal`. It's not a signal, it's a signal *set* or a signal *mask*.